# Ambiguous reference to member 'first(where:)' error when referencing child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I am writing an iOS application and have a child view controller that I am trying to reference. The child view controller is the delegate of the parent.

At the top of the parent view controller, I have: `fileprivate var cameraViewController: CameraViewController<AnyObject>?`

In `viewDidLoad()`, I have

```
guard let cameraController = childViewControllers.first as? CameraViewController else  {
            fatalError("Check storyboard for missing CameraViewController")
        }

        cameraViewController = cameraController
```

However, I'm getting the error: `Ambiguous reference to member 'first(where:)'`

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? I only have one child view controller for the parent.

Comment: what do you have `childViewControllers` declared as?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann That's a property of `UIViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy then shouldn't he be referencing it as `self.childViewControllers` (assuming the code is in a UIViewController subclass)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann `self` is optional in many cases in Swift.

Comment: I suspect this might be one of those cases where the compiler gets lost inside a conditional unwrap.  If you put `childViewControllers.first` in parentheses, does it work?

Comment: Cannot replicate the error. Clean and Build your project; see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks everyone and sorry for the ambiguity of my question. I left out the detail that I was trying to make the CameraViewController the delegate of its parent. I edited the question and added the answer that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CameraViewController needs to be the same everywhere. When I instantiated cameraViewController as a CameraViewController, that needed to be reflected in the second part of the code. The second part should look like this:

```
guard let cameraController = childViewControllers.first as? CameraViewController<AnyObject> else  {
            fatalError("Check storyboard for missing CameraViewController")
        }

        cameraViewController = cameraController
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce. This is the entire code in my app's single view controller file:

```
import UIKit
class CameraViewController : UIViewController {}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate var cameraViewController: CameraViewController?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let cameraController = childViewControllers.first as? CameraViewController else  {
            fatalError("Check storyboard for missing CameraViewController")
        }
        cameraViewController = cameraController
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine.